# Bootbox Ajax post is empty in callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am new to coding and I am trying to create a button to use bootstrap 5 to delete a client form a sql database.

I am using datatables and the button is formed like this:

```
<li><button class="dropdown-item testing" name= ' + item.client_id + ' aria-label="delplan" type="button"><i class="far fa-trash-alt styleicon"></i>Verwijder</button></li>
```

I am using the folowing script to retrieve to open the modal with bootbox and get the ID from the name tag in my button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var table = $('#clientTable').DataTable();
      $("#clientTable").on("click", ".testing", function () {
           var id = $(this).attr('name');
            console.log(id); // this is correctly showing the id in the console !
 bootbox.confirm({
    title: "Verwijder client?",
    message: "Weet je zeker dat je deze client wilt verwijderen van de database?",
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel'
        },
        confirm: {
            label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirm'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result) {
        var id = $(this).attr('name');// the post is empty and the console says undefined, so tried to get it here to, but still undefined.
        
        var p = loadPrompt();
        if(result === false){
        console.log('clicked no: ' + id); // console log clicked no undefined..
        p.inform('Client is niet verwijderd!'); 
        }
        else{ 
         
        
        console.log('clicked yes: ' + id); // console log clicked yes undefined..
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "client_delete_client.php",
        data: {id: id}, // post request is happening in network tab but no data is send??
        success: function(data) {
            
             $('#clientTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            
p.success('Client is succesvol verwijderd! ');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("ERROR : Something went wrong! Try again our contact the database administrator" + error);
            p.error('Fout in het verwijderen van client !');
        }
    });
        
        
        }
    }
});
  });
});
</script>
```

I do not understand why my script is not posting the `var id` to `url client_delete_client.php` after the client clicked yes? I hope than there is someone here that can help me. Because the id is loged in the console at first but after that is is undefined?

Comment: Anyone has suggestions??:(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one of JavaScript scope. Inside your callback function `this` refers to something else, probably the callback function itself but a `console.log(this)` would confirm it.

The solution is to create a reference to your button right after the click event:

```js
$("#clientTable").on("click", ".testing", function () {
    const btn = this;
}
```

then refer to `btn` elsewhere in your code

```js
const id = $(btn).attr('name');
```

I recommend that you do some reading about scope in JavaScript, particularly with how it affects the `this` variable (but also other variables) because it's something that trips up a lot of developers.